# Converting JavaScript into Python bytecode

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am trying to execute simple JavaScript code in a pure Python environment (Google AppEngine).

I've tried PYJON, but it does not seem mature enough for real use(it does not handle eg forward referenced functions or do-while and it hangs on array usage).

One idea would be to use pynarcissus to convert JavaScript into a syntax tree and than convert this tree jnto a Python AST which could be compiled into Python bytecode.

Has anybody done this before?
Any problems with this idea?

Comment: Why Python bytecode and not Python source code? Do you need to programmatically translate the JS?

Comment: If you're trying to run Javascript on GAE, it seems like converting to Java would be a better bet - you can run on JS the JVM via Rhino.

Comment: I was thinking that AST is the closest to the parsed JavaScript. And in the end I will need bytecode for execution. But Python source could can also be translated programmatically to bytecode.

Comment: The existing JavaScript code needs access existing Python code. And doing some weird mixture of 3 languages, is not something I really want to maintain over the next years

Comment: Why not translate the JavaScript to Python?

Comment: Which tool translates JavaScript to Python?

Comment: Your brain translates JS to Python.

Comment: Syntax is far from the only difference between Javascript and Python; simply translating the ASTs is not going to cut it. And I really hope this isn't user code you're talking about executing that way.

Comment: @NickJohnson I'd be glad if you could make your comment a little more constructive. Why translating the ASTs is not going to work? I did this before with other languages and it wasn't easy, but worked.

Comment: @PedroWerneck Well, for instance, Javascript uses prototype-based OO, while Python uses class-based OO. Javscript's casting rules between data types are different, and it has a totally different standard library. Built in objects, like strings, have different methods with different behaviours. These are just a few of the differences between the two languages.

Comment: @NickJohnson Having differences is not a problem. Libraries and builtins can be mocked in a post-processor, the model too. With the casting rules you have a point, and that deserves more attention, but I don't see it as impeditive. You can easily generate Python code that mimics Javascript's casting rules.

Comment: @NickJohnson Maybe you're forgetting that fact that this won't generate Python code, but byte-code. It doesn't have to be easily readable or pythonic, as long as it runs correctly. It would be terrible to convert [] == 0 into int(bool([])) == 0 and have that code written down for someone to maintain, I agree, but as byte-code is fine, and it runs correctly.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I'm not forgetting that - making the object models match, changing the casting rules, and so forth, is all way more than just AST rewriting.

Comment: @NickJohnson As I said, it's hard work, but it can be done.

Comment: @PedroWerneck And as I said, it's not simply a matter of converting the AST into a Python AST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar using [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), for VBScript and for a new language I've been working on for a while, but instead of building the AST and then convert to a Python AST, I'd build the Python AST straight on, using its node classes and occasionally subclassing and overriding some that wouldn't fit particularly well.

Since you can rely on pynarcissus to build an AST for Javascript, converting the AST is probably easier, but I think it's worth checking if using its parser to build a Python AST isn't a better approach.

There are no inherent problems with this approach, as far as I know, as long as the languages can be syntactically reduced to a common dialect. It's hard work, but it can be done. I did this because I didn't have a parser available and writing one to just build an AST would make no sense. For VBScript I was dealing only with recorded macros, so code was very stable, mostly one-liners.

Comment: I don't want to modify the pretty complex parser (so I could keep it in sync with the orginal).

Comment: There are inherent problems: Python and Javascript are not simply the same language with different syntaxes.

Comment: That is not an inherent problem. That's a problem, that has a solution, which is finding a common subset in both ASTs. We're talking about ASTs, so the code and syntax where they came from doesn't matter, as long as they can be reduced to the same subset. Your argument that they are different languages doesn't point an inherent problem with this approach, since Python and VBScript aren't the same language either, and I did it. Actually, I had more problems parsing the ambiguous '=' in VBScript than with creating a valid Python AST.

Comment: It seems nobody has done it (for JavaScript) before (at least I found nobody) and the challenge would be to convert JavaScript AST to Python AST and to create a runtime environment (scoping, prototypes, JavaScript classes). The benefits would be a portable (pure Python) and maintainable solution(parser and byte code generation exists)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there are no complete and robust implementations of Javascript interpreters on Python. Your best option is probably to deploy an alternate version of your app with the Rhino interpreter in Java, and call this as a web service with the main version of your app.